# IMX6 + webengine doesn't display latest website state, why?

Tags: imx6, webengine

I've written a simple website in html, css, js. No error and everything display's fine in the chromium desktop version.
The problem is, that i would like to display it on the IMX6 Solo + webengine.
For developing reason's i used Apache2 and just did something like ./webengine http://172.XX.XX.XXX/index.html for the IMX.
At first it worked absolutely fine, but if i would like to change something in my website code and try to refresh it on the IMX6, then nothing new happens. It still show's the old version of the website.
In chromium everything that i code new appears .. but not on the IMX.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

It's the browser-cache.
Solved the problem by manually clearing it.